# Nested Object Deserialization of JSON results in an empty object

Tags: c#, ajax, json, deserialization, javascriptserializer

Good day

I am attempting to deserialize a JSON object to C# classes using a Javascriptserializer. This object contains a nested object. Here is a representation of the object:

```
[{"ObjA":"FOO",
  "SubObjA":{
    "A":0,
    "B":true,
    "C":2,
    "D":0.2
    },
  "ObjB":false,
  "ObjC":295,
  }]
```

In c#, I created the classes for these:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public string ObjA { get; set; }
    public Collection<SubObjA> SubObjA { get; set; }
    public bool ObjB { get; set; }
    public int ObjC { get; set; }


}

public class SubObjA
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public bool B { get; set; }
    public int C { get; set; }
    public decimal D { get; set; }
}
```

When Deserializing the object, I see that the SubObjA Collection does not populate (Count = 0)

```
var Helper = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<ClassA[]>(Request["TheJSONIAmDeserializing"]);
```

Why is the collection not populating? (Tagged AJAX because of the Request[""] )

Comment: Not the actual class and property names, Had to make changes to obscure the real code

Comment: In my version, everything but the collection populates correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SubObjA in your example is a single object but in your class it is a collection, so JSON should look like

```
[{"ObjA":"FOO",
  "SubObjA":[{
    "A":0,
    "B":true,
    "C":2,
    "D":0.2
    }],
  "ObjB":false,
  "ObjC":295,
  }]
```

Note brackets around SubObjA.

Comment: hot damn, you're right.  JSON.Stringify only returned the bracers and not the square brackets because it is currently populated with 1 item in the collection.

Comment: thank you once again. couldn't click why it wasn't working, everything seemed right